# Wordpress won't upload images correctly

Tags: wordpress

I just transferred a website's files to a new directory and took it live. Wordpress suddenly won't upload images all the way, just a blank square showing up. I can see the image, however, if I click on "edit image". It won't appear on the front end at all through the visual builder. I'm using the Divi theme 3.26.8 and Wordpress 5.2.2.

All file permissions on the uploads folder and folders within are at 755, but I did notice that the month folders for July and August of this year were not created. I tried adding an image to the media library and the 08 folder for August was not automatically added. When I create the folder manually, Media Library still will not upload to the folder. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's silly that I missed this, but there was an upload path in the database that needed updating from the old directory and I somehow missed it. In case anyone runs into the same problem, I went into the database in phpmyadmin, went into  wp_options, found upload_path and edited to add the correct directory to the path. Voila! everything started working correctly!